# Designing a blocking method until a value in the dictionary changes

Tags: c#

I am currently attempting to design a method that blocks until a value changes in a dictionary. Here I am using the WaitForOpenSpot method.This is only a rough sketch. I am aware that it is currently not thread safe. I'll eventually add the locking/unlocking later. For now I wanted to know if there was a better way of doing this ? Any other suggestions would also be appreciated.

```
Class AccountStatus
{
  static bool OpenSpot = false;

  static private Dictionary<String, int> Transfer = InitializeContainer();

  static Dictionary<String , int> InitializeContainer ()
  {
       Dictionary<String, int> Transfer = new Dictionary<String, int>()
       Transfer.add("stat",0);
  }

  static void  Changestatus(string str , int val) //str = stat 
  {
      Transfer[str] = val;
      if(val == 1)
      {
          OpenSpot = true
      }        
  } 

  static void WaitForOpenSpot()
  {
      while(!OpenSpot)
      {
          Thread.sleep(2);
      }
  } 
}//end class
```

Comment: Do you have the option to use .Net 4.0+?

Comment: Yes I am using .net 4.0 - VS2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) class.

Adopting from your code to give you a rough example (may not compile):

```
private static AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false); 

static void WaitForOpenSpot()
{  
    resetEvent.WaitOne();
}

static void ChangeStatus(string str, int val)
{
   Transfer[str] = val;
   if (val == 1)
   {
       resetEvent.Set();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but Isnt AutoResetEvent suppose to be static here ?

Answer (score 0):

The normal pattern for something like this is to use `Monitor.Wait`/`Monitor.PulseAll`.  To use those methods, one should define a wait condition which can only be changed inside a lock, and have any code that does something that might change that condition do a `PulseAll` on the lock after having done so.

For example:
    Dictionary myDict;

```
//Code that waits for magic key value:
lock(myDict)
{
    int myNumber;
    while (!myDict.TryGetValue(myKey, out myNumber) || myNumber < valueOfInterest)
        Monitor.Wait(myDict);
}

//Code that changes anything in myDict:
lock(myDict)
{
    myDict[theKey] = theValue;
    Monitor.PulseAll(myDict);
}
```

Any time anything changes in the Dictionary, all waiting threads which are waiting for a certain key to hold a certain value will, one by one, check to see whether it does and either proceed or go back to waiting.

Note that the correctness of this code would not be affected if `Monitor.Wait` sometimes spontaneously returned early without being pulsed.  Although `Monitor.Wait` won't generally spontaneously wake up, code which is correctly written can generally tolerate such wakeups, and code which would be broken by such wakeups is generally broken in other ways as well.