# Why does this application not hang and how is it waiting for a client to connect?

Tags: c#

I am learning some basic C# programming.

Was following a tutorial and the main function has a loop like this:

```
class Server
{
    static List<Client> _clients = new();
    static TcpListener _listener = new(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),7892);
    
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        _listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            var client = new Client(_listener.AcceptTcpClient());
            _clients.Add(client);
            Console.WriteLine(_clients.Count+ " total clients");
        }
    }
}
```

Since this is an infinite never ending while loop, why does the program not hang like it does when I accidently create an infinite loop in other scripts?

Additionally, when I ran this code, I was surprised to find it was not adding a new client every loop, but only when a client connected, how exactly is it waiting on the `AcceptTcpClient()` function? I looked at the code for this function, its not clear to me how its waiting...

```
public TcpClient AcceptTcpClient()
{
    if (!_active)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.net_stopped);
    }

    Socket acceptedSocket = _serverSocket!.Accept();
    return new TcpClient(acceptedSocket);
}
```

Comment: What is `Client` type?

Comment: Its my own class that holds a reference to the `TcpClient`  and a string for Username.

Comment: Can I assume you execute this code on a Console app, and that's the only thread your app has? In that case, `AcceptTcpClient` blocks the thread (similar to `Console.ReadLine`).

Comment: `Accept` is blocking

Comment: Yes i know `Accept` is blocking but I can't seem to navigate to see the code on how it does it. When I F12 the method it says: `Cannot navigate to symbol under caret.` So i still don't know how exactly its blocking.

Comment: You can follow along here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,0a804cd23f7a0b14 but at some point it's going to call out to the Win32 API/Winsock here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,d95674fb99b757a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: in the future, putting a debugger breakpoint can help you find out why easily.

The [`AcceptTcpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient?view=net-6.0) method is a blocking call, similar to `Console.ReadLine()`:

> ```cs
> // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
> // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
> TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
> ```

So while your `while` loop would run forever, it doesn't consume resources (usually CPU) continously like this loop:

```cs
while (true) i++;
```

If you put a debugger, you will notice it stops at `AcceptTcpClient` until a client connects. That's why your program doesn't freeze since it's waiting and not doing anything. However note that if you do this in an UI thread of a WPF app for example, the GUI would *probably* freeze since it blocks the thread.

If you are curious about how blocking function is implemented, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839029/designing-a-blocking-method-until-a-value-in-the-dictionary-changes) is probably the closest I could find on SO but nowadays people generally want to avoid it (since it blocks your thread) and try making things asynchronous (using Task) instead. You should actually use [`AcceptTcpClientAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync?view=net-6.0) if possible.

Comment: Ah so its something to do with `lock` keyword then ?

Comment: @WDUK yes and no. [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) locks an object and "Any other thread is blocked from acquiring the lock and waits until the lock is released". It's up to your implementation on how to block it. Someone could use `Thread.Sleep` or `AutoResetEvent` like suggested in the question I linked. They could use mutex lock, monitor, semaphore or whatever mechanic under the hood, not our concern.

Comment: @WDUK also see my latest edit. Blocking is actually not good since it keeps the thread running and wouldn't release it back to the thread pool. For modern apps, async methods are preferred if possible..

Comment: I'll look into async once i got the basics understood ! Thanks !